# Is a holomorphic vector bundle on a projective variety locally trivial in the Zariski topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

By the GAGA principle we know that a holomorphic vector bundle E->X is analitically isomorphic to an algebraic one, say F->X, and by definition F is locally trivial in the Zariski topology. But since the isomorphism between E and F is analytic, I fail to see if this implies that E is Zariski locally trivial too.

I hope the answer is not "trivially yes" for some stupid reason, but I cannot guarantee that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get (analytic) trivializations of E over Zariski-open sets just by composing a trivialization of E with the isomorphism between E and F. Of course, you do not get algebraic trivializations, but for this you would need an algebraic structure on E in the first place.

Comment: It seems to work, and it seems that my question was trivial, as I suspected. Thank you anyway, for your clarification :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's probably worth noting that etale-locally trivial principal GL(n)-bundles are automatically Zariski-locally trivial.  This isn't necessarily true for general G.

Comment: I don't see how the situation depends on the group G; can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

My memory is fuzzy, but when you compute algebraic bundle cohomology, and it happens to be 0 here because of GAGA, I think, on all affine subschemes, wouldn't it automatically mean the bundle is locally trivial?